# How to run a VBA add-in macro from Excel using the Application.OnKey shortcut?

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

I have an **Excel add-in** in which I have several macros, some that have the `Application.OnKey` method to enable the user to use a specific **keyboard shortcut** to run a certain macro.

Accessing the code in the add-in requires a password.

This is a simple example of a macro:

```
Sub refreshMySelection()
Application.Selection.Calculate
Application.OnKey "^{ENTER}", "refreshMySelection"
End Sub
```

This is meant to allow the user to refresh selected Excel cells by only typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However, for some reason, **Excel does not automatically recognize this shortcut**. Unless I manually open the add-in and execute the above macro, then only the current active workbook would do the job i.e. refresh selected cells when typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

@ [Thinkingcap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266562/thinkingcap), your suggestion works perfect, thanks !

Add the below in the addin

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Application.OnKey "^{ENTER}", "refreshMySelection"
End Sub
```